# Multiple web3 instances on a Single Page

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, contract-deployment, gui

Is it normal/possible to use 2 instances of the `web3` object?

In my app, a user can

- trigger the deployment of new contracts by clicking a button on the UI. The gas comes from a wallet that belongs to the app
- send ether to the deployed contract **on the same page** (made simple via a button on the page, contract then sends tokens to user)

In this scenario, is it recommended to have 2 `web3` instances,

1. one using the `web3` belonging to the app
2. one injected by the user's browser (eg: Metamask)

If so, is there a naming convention for the 2 `web3` instances, like `web3App` and `web3Browser`?

Is this also an unusual scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to run 2 instances of web3.js. I am not aware of any naming convention for each web3 instance.

On the readme of web3 on github 
(https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/README.md), there are some instructions to run several instances of web3:

> web3.js version 0.14.0 supports multiple instances of web3 object. To
>   migrate to this version, please follow the guide:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();
```